# How to make nodejs and react use different ports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

package.json file :

```
"start": "concurrently \"nodemon index.js --port 3000 \" \"react-scripts start --port 3000 \" ",
"start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start --port 3000\" ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "server": "NODE_ENV=production node index.js",
```

so I can run both nodejs server and react at the same time. Either with `npm run server` and `npm start` or just with `npm start` which includes both

but because I have PORT=3001 in .env file 
both server and react try to run on 3001 server. Of course it gives error "Something is already running on port 3001."

How can I make react have its own port 3000? Option --port 3000 do not help

Answer (score 0):

You can override environment variables for each script.

For example:

```
{
  "start": "concurrently \"PORT=3000 nodemon index.js\" \"PORT=3001 react-scripts start\""
}
```

Comment: good. It works. Otherwise,Why react get port variable from .env? I never specified it anywhere? In which code part it happens that it chooses 3001 instead of default 3000?

Comment: I used  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
to run react app also on that address, even though it is on 3000. Why I do not get it appear there?

Comment: react-scripts use .env [by default](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env), starting 0.5.0 version

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the ports explicitly either on the CLI or via your script.

```
{
  "start:client": "PORT=3001 react-scripts start",
  "start:server": "PORT=3000 nodemon index.js",
  "start": "concurrently \"start:client\" \"start:server\""
}
```

This should make it easier to read.